# How to force no-caching of specific external resources?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

My website displays traffic cams amongst other resources. They change every minute. I have to use the &nonce= to override the caching in order to get an update every minute. However, ALL of those get cached and the storage profile (specifically image caching) gets into gigabytes quickly.

As the traffic cam resources are out of my control (and they don't specify no-cache, but they DO prevent CORS), I see these options to prevent caching of images (but keep for other resources).

1. Specify (what?) in the request so that it's not cached.
   Using xhr to specify no-cache and createObjectURL would fail b/c of CORS. And, can't bypass CORS b/c it's a PWA, not meant to have a local proxy server.
2. Override the response (headers!) with some middleware? (which?)
3. Clear only images in the cache every minute. (how?).
4. A better option I'm missing?

(Using straight js, no jquery).